# C - fwrite() from volatile source

Tags: c, fwrite, volatile

I have some memory that a coprocessor can modify. I have marked my pointer to it as volatile, but if I use that memory as the source in an fwrite do I have to worry about linux caching (kernel postpones the copy until after the coprocessor has changed the data at that location) or anything else?

For example:

```
volatile My_Data_t* samples;
fwrite((void *) samples, 4, 1, fp);
```

Comment: Note that unlike [`write(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write), `fwrite` may get further buffered in the C standard library.

Comment: With buffered i/o, a copy has been made to another array before a flush.  That still doesn't solve the problem. Nor does `write` make this call any more safe from concurrency issues than `fwrite`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is "yes".

`volatile` doesn't add any extra protection to concurrency issues. It's just a hint to the compiler not to cache the contents in a register between successive accesses.

I don't know the layout of a `My_Data_t` type, but you are writing at least four of them out at a time.  If you are saying the co-processor can modify this array at any time, it's quite possible that during the fwrite call, a subset of the items in your array are modified.

Does your co-processor have any capability of respecting a "lock" mechanism?  That's ultimately what you need.

Comment: The coprocessor can respect a lock. If I lock the memory until the `fwrite` returns, am I 'safe'?

Comment: As long as **both** threads take the lock when accessing or changing the contents of `samples`. So if you wrap the `fwrite` call with a lock/unlock, and the co-processor doesn't attempt to write to `samples` unless it has the lock, you should be ok.